# Sacar el MIN y MAX con php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy realizando esta consulta en mysql con php y obtengo la información agrupada correctamente.

```
SELECT dias, fechas, SUM(carne_arabe) Total FROM base WHERE dias = 'Lunes' AND mes = 'Junio' AND anio = '2020' GROUP BY fechas
```

Obtengo el resultado agrupado de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, necesito sacar el MIN que sería "29,094.98" y MAX que sería "67.753.58" de ese resultado entre esos datos...
Alguna idea colegas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(t.Total) as minimo, max(t.Total) as maximo 
from
(SELECT dias, fechas, SUM(carne_arabe) Total 
 FROM base 
 WHERE dias = 'Lunes' AND mes = 'Junio' AND anio = '2020' 
 GROUP BY fechas) t
```

Debes hacer un **select** cuya **cláusula** **from** sea la consulta original que ya tienes, la consulta dentro de la **cláusula** **from** devuelve un conjunto de resultados, es decir devuelve una tabla con los campos **dias**, **fechas** y **total**, y es sobre ese conjunto de resultados que vas a realizar una consulta para obtener el **total máximo** y el **total mínimo**.

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funcionó a la perfección. Agradezco tu ayuda y comentarios.